# Clear temporary list without clearing where I assign it to

Tags: c++

I have a 'Slate' which is essentially the current screen, in that screen are 'pages' that hold 'items' up to 12 in size, because that is all that will fit on the screen, so I have tried to check, once it reaches 12 items, to make a new page, but the code listed below just leaves no items in either page 1 or page 2

```
int pageItems = 0;    
std::list<item*> tempList;
page* temp = new page;  
for (std::list<item*>::iterator iter = items.begin(); iter != items.end(); ++iter)
{
    tempList.push_back((*iter));
    if (pageItems >= 13) {
        page_Count++;
        temp->items = tempList;
        pages.push_back(temp);
        tempList.clear();
        temp->items.clear();
        pageItems = 0;
    }
    pageItems++;
}
```

Page is a class that holds std::list, but should only handle 12, and then a new page will be created with the next amount, if it goes above 12, new class
And slate is the class that holds std::list as well as std::list, the item one is just so its easier to create a class, because originally it didnt have pages, and now I just feed 'items' into 'pages' according to how many are given to the slate

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
    temp->items.clear();
```

You seem to clear the page after adding it to your list of pages

Comment: Yeah I'm clearing it because I want to use it in the next loop, and I have already added it to the 'pages' list, so clearing it shouldnt matter(?) (not sure, thats how it works in java and im new to C++)

Comment: It is a pointer so it points to the same memory as that you added to your list. I guess what you want to do is allocate a new page instead ( temp = new page ). Just remember to free the memory you allocate later